# bring the customer id from auto search box and then redirect to it the customer update page

Tags: javascript, django, redirect, django-views, django-templates

I have a Django project. it has the functionality to create a customer and its working fine.I have added the auto search box in the same template to search already created customer. when i enter word its suggesting the names already saved in the database. but when i clicked a name its **displaying in the search box as [object object] not the correct name **. and I created button to selected customer to update . but when i clicked the button its saying "Please select a customer from the autocomplete list" i need to find whats the problem in my code.

I need to correctly show the selected result from auto suggest search box and when i clicked the update button it should redirect to the customer update page. here is the html code of my auto complete search box"

```
`<div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div id="autocomplete" class="autocomplete">
          <input class="autocomplete-input" />
          <ul class="autocomplete-result-list"></ul>
        </div>
        <button id="update-customer-button" type="button" onclick="redirectToUpdateCustomer()">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>"`
```

and here is my JavaScript for the auto complete search and redirecting to the update page"

```
`const selectedCustomerId = null;

// Existing Autocomplete setup
new Autocomplete('#autocomplete', {
  search: input => {
    console.log(input);
    const url = `/master/get_customers/?search=${input}`;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data.payload);
          resolve(data.payload);
        });
    });
  },
  renderResult: (result, props) => {
    let group = '';
    if (result.index % 3 === 0) {
      group = '<li class="group">Group</li>';
    }

    // Construct the attribute string from the 'props' object
    const attributes = Object.entries(props).map(([key, value]) => `${key}="${value}"`).join(' ');

    return `
      ${group}
      <li ${attributes} data-id="${result.id}">
        <div class="wiki-title">
          ${result.first_name} ${result.last_name}
        </div>
      </li>
    `;
  },
  onSelection: (item) => {
    // Set the value of the search box with the selected customer's name
    const selectedName = item.querySelector('.wiki-title').textContent.trim();
    document.querySelector('.autocomplete-input').value = selectedName;

    // Get the selected customer's ID from the 'data-id' attribute
    selectedCustomerId = item.dataset.id;
  },
});

// Function to redirect to the update customer page
function redirectToUpdateCustomer() {
  // Check if a customer has been selected
  if (selectedCustomerId) {
    // Redirect to the update_customer URL with the correct customer ID
    window.location.href = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/master/update_customer/${selectedCustomerId}/`;
  } else {
    // Show an alert message
    alert('Please select a customer from the autocomplete list.');
  }
}` h
```

here is autocomplete script tag `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@trevoreyre/autocomplete-js"></script>` i also have view function for the autocomplete search box written views.py "

```
def get_customers(request):
    search = request.GET.get('search')
    payload = []

    if search:
        try:
            objs = Customer.objects.filter(
                Q(first_name__icontains=search) | Q(last_name__icontains=search)
            )
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            objs = []

        for obj in objs:
            payload.append({
                'first_name': obj.first_name,
                'last_name': obj.last_name,
                'id': obj.id,
            })


    
    return JsonResponse({
        'status': True,
        'payload': payload
    })
```